# Accessing the Quick Panel user input in a Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, plugins, sublimetext3

Is it possible to use the Sublime Text 3 quick panel to retrieve user input as the `goto_line` command does?

When I hit <kbd>CTRL+G</kbd>, a quick panel appears and I can hit enter with any value. I cannot do this when I use this panel manually

If I use the quickpanel without values, I cannot validate it and therefore cannot retrieve the value inserted by the user.

I'm trying to do a plugin to create a Lua addon skeleton for a game, and I need to retrieve multiple user inputs as follows: [image]

Is it possible to use the quick panel or I must use the `show_input_panel` multiple times ?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no way to accept arbitrary input from a quick panel. Input is simply used to fuzzy filter the list.

For your plugin, here's a crazy idea: maybe you can create a snippet with text and fields for the input you want. Your plugin can have a command which when run creates a new scratch buffer where you insert this snippet. Once the user has filled out the fields, they can either run another command, or simply close the view (your plugin should have a listener for that event) to execute and do whatever.

Comment: here what I came up with actually: https://github.com/kitensei/sublime-wildstar-skeleton/blob/master/WildstarAddonBuilder/WildstarAddonBuilder.py